# Generate TSIG keyring (as encoded byte string) for DNS Update

Tags: python, dns, kerberos, dnspython

I am trying to use python DNS module ([dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org/)) to create (`add`) new DNS record.

Documentation specifies how to create update http://www.dnspython.org/examples.html :

```py
import dns.tsigkeyring
import dns.update
import sys

keyring = dns.tsigkeyring.from_text({
    'host-example.' : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=='
})

update = dns.update.Update('dyn.test.example', keyring=keyring)
update.replace('host', 300, 'a', sys.argv[1])
```

But it does not precise, how to actually generate keyring string that can be passed to `dns.tsigkeyring.from_text()` method in the first place.

What is the correct way to generate the key? I am using krb5 at my organization.

Comment: Which nameserver do you use? `bind` ships with a `dnssec-keygen` command that you can use to generate TSIG keys

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Server is running on Microsoft AD DNS with GSS-TSIG. I have double-checked and it seems that `dnspython` does not support GSS-TSIG and is not going to in near future https://github.com/rthalley/dnspython/blob/master/doc/rfc.rst - for BIND I think you can add `dnssec-keygen` as answer - I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Server is running on Microsoft AD DNS with GSS-TSIG.

TSIG and GSS-TSIG are different beasts – the former uses a static preshared key that can be simply copied from the server, but the latter uses Kerberos (GSSAPI) to negotiate a session key for every transaction.

At the time when this thread was originally posted, dnspython 1.x did not have any support for GSS-TSIG whatsoever.

(The handshake does not result in a static key that could be converted to a regular TSIG keyring; instead the GSSAPI library itself must be called to build an authenticator – dnspython 1.x could not do that, although dnspython 2.1 finally can.)

If you are trying to update an Active Directory DNS server, BIND's **nsupdate** command-line tool supports GSS-TSIG (and sometimes it even works). You should be able to run it through *subprocess* and simply feed the necessary updates via stdin.

```py
cmds = [f'zone {dyn_zone}\n',
        f'del {fqdn}\n',
        f'add {fqdn} 60 TXT "{challenge}"\n',
        f'send\n']
subprocess.run(["nsupdate", "-g"],
               input="".join(cmds).encode(),
               check=True)
```

As with most Kerberos client applications, nsupdate expects the credentials to be already present in the environment (that is, you need to have already obtained a TGT using `kinit` beforehand; or alternatively, if a recent version of MIT Krb5 is used, you can point `$KRB5_CLIENT_KTNAME` to the keytab containing the client credentials).

Update: **dnspython 2.1** finally has the necessary pieces for GSS-TSIG, but creating the keyring is currently a *very* manual process – you have to call the GSSAPI library and process the TKEY negotiation yourself. The code for doing so is included at the bottom.

(The Python code below can be passed a custom `gssapi.Credentials` object, but otherwise it looks for credentials in the environment just like nsupdate does.)

```py
import dns.rdtypes.ANY.TKEY
import dns.resolver
import dns.update
import gssapi
import socket
import time
import uuid

def _build_tkey_query(token, key_ring, key_name):
    inception_time = int(time.time())
    tkey = dns.rdtypes.ANY.TKEY.TKEY(dns.rdataclass.ANY,
                                     dns.rdatatype.TKEY,
                                     dns.tsig.GSS_TSIG,
                                     inception_time,
                                     inception_time,
                                     3,
                                     dns.rcode.NOERROR,
                                     token,
                                     b"")

    query = dns.message.make_query(key_name,
                                   dns.rdatatype.TKEY,
                                   dns.rdataclass.ANY)
    query.keyring = key_ring
    query.find_rrset(dns.message.ADDITIONAL,
                     key_name,
                     dns.rdataclass.ANY,
                     dns.rdatatype.TKEY,
                     create=True).add(tkey)
    return query

def _probe_server(server_name, zone):
    gai = socket.getaddrinfo(str(server_name),
                             "domain",
                             socket.AF_UNSPEC,
                             socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    for af, sf, pt, cname, sa in gai:
        query = dns.message.make_query(zone, "SOA")
        res = dns.query.udp(query, sa[0], timeout=2)
        return sa[0]

def gss_tsig_negotiate(server_name, server_addr, creds=None):
    # Acquire GSSAPI credentials
    gss_name = gssapi.Name(f"DNS@{server_name}",
                           gssapi.NameType.hostbased_service)
    gss_ctx = gssapi.SecurityContext(name=gss_name,
                                     creds=creds,
                                     usage="initiate")

    # Name generation tips: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2930#section-2.1
    key_name = dns.name.from_text(f"{uuid.uuid4()}.{server_name}")
    tsig_key = dns.tsig.Key(key_name, gss_ctx, dns.tsig.GSS_TSIG)

    key_ring = {key_name: tsig_key}
    key_ring = dns.tsig.GSSTSigAdapter(key_ring)

    token = gss_ctx.step()
    while not gss_ctx.complete:
        tkey_query = _build_tkey_query(token, key_ring, key_name)
        response = dns.query.tcp(tkey_query, server_addr, timeout=5)
        if not gss_ctx.complete:
            # Original comment:
            # https://github.com/rthalley/dnspython/pull/530#issuecomment-658959755
            # "this if statement is a bit redundant, but if the final token comes
            # back with TSIG attached the patch to message.py will automatically step
            # the security context. We dont want to excessively step the context."
            token = gss_ctx.step(response.answer[0][0].key)

    return key_name, key_ring

def gss_tsig_update(zone, update_msg, creds=None):
    # Find the SOA of our zone
    answer = dns.resolver.resolve(zone, "SOA")
    soa_server = answer.rrset[0].mname
    server_addr = _probe_server(soa_server, zone)

    # Get the GSS-TSIG key
    key_name, key_ring = gss_tsig_negotiate(soa_server, server_addr, creds)

    # Dispatch the update
    update_msg.use_tsig(keyring=key_ring,
                        keyname=key_name,
                        algorithm=dns.tsig.GSS_TSIG)
    response = dns.query.tcp(update_msg, server_addr)
    return response
```